# PHP URL Path needs to be different from Folder Path

Tags: php, url, redirect

Using php is there a way to take this path

```
Path: /abc/def/files/websitedomain/from/this/folder/(mynewpages.php location)
```

and redirect it in here

```
Path: /abc/def/files/www/com/(index.php location)
```

so my result is

```
website.com/mynewpages
```

This is my only option available at the moment. The site I am working has been a very interesting experience.

EDIT: None of the solutions provided solved my problem. However, you all got me thinking. I was able to .htaccess file via PHP

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen(".htaccess", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = " copied text + Hello World ";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

That worked. Now I just need the best way to write my path needs into .htaccess.

Comment: Use .htaccess to redirect

Comment: If you just want a redirect `header('LOCATION:yourLocationHere'); die;`

Comment: I would love to use .htaccess. As previously stated, this currently my only option at the moment. I am trying to remain positive and not turn to insulting the developer. :)

Comment: Have you tried @PHPglue's suggestion in mynewpages.php? Another thing that might work (never used them) is a meta redirect tag in the HTML of the page.

Comment: @CMiller it throws a 404 error. I'm at least trying to learn more about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score -2):

To redirect outside of the DocumentRoot you need to use mod_rewrite or equivalent. It's not safe to do this via PHP includes, and a HTTP redirect (Location header) won't work.

If you're using Apache, it'll look something like this (but the question isn't clear enough to give specifics):

```
<VirtualHost 80>
    DocumentRoot "/abc/def/files/websitedomain"
    ... 
    <Directory "/abc/def/files/websitedomain/from/this/folder">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule "^/abc/def/files/websitedomain/from/this/folder/(.*)$" "/abc/def/files/www/com/$1"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? My php knowledge is really getting tested atm.

Comment: @Straughnhold `mod_rewrite` is part of the Apache server, nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Ah that is what I thought. I misread your message :). The only other possibilties are with AJAX or JSON, but I don't have any experience with either of those to know if that is even a possibility.